# SQL, combine two aggregates of same table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, aggregate

I have the following table, which contains number of operations performed by `operator` of a specific `department` in a specific `date` for each `target_type`. `sum1` and `sum2` are the number of operation 1 and operation 2 on the specific day, the interpretation of operations in question is indicated by the `operation_type` column.

```
statistic_id | department | operator | operation_type | target_type | sum1 | sum2 | date |
```

I would query the table to collect statistics for `operation_type 1` on a `department 1` in a specific time period grouped by `operator` and `operation_type` as follows

```
SELECT operator, target_type, SUM(sum1) AS op1, SUM(sum2) AS op2 FROM statistics
WHERE
  department = 1 AND
  operation_type = 1 AND
  (date BETWEEN in_start_date AND in_end_date)
GROUP BY operator, target_type
ORDER BY operator, target_type;
```

As well, I would query the table to collect statistics for `operation_type 2` on the same department and time interval grouped by the same criteria

```
SELECT operator, target_type, SUM(sum1) AS op3, SUM(sum2) AS op4 FROM statistics
WHERE
  department = 1 AND
  operation_type = 2 AND
  (date BETWEEN in_start_date AND in_end_date)
GROUP BY operator, target_type
ORDER BY operator, target_type;
```

I would like to combine the query results, so I would get result like

```
operator | target_type | op1 | op2 | op3 | op4
```

How do I join the table with itself via aggregating different columns based on some common and some diverse criteria, yet grouping by the same set of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation in your sums:

```
SELECT operator,
       target_type,
       SUM(CASE WHEN operation_type = 1 THEN sum1 ELSE 0 END) AS op1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN operation_type = 1 THEN sum2 ELSE 0 END) AS op2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN operation_type = 2 THEN sum1 ELSE 0 END) AS op3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN operation_type = 2 THEN sum2 ELSE 0 END) AS op4
FROM statistics
WHERE department = 1 AND
      date BETWEEN in_start_date AND in_end_date
GROUP BY operator, target_type
ORDER BY operator, target_type
```

This makes a single pass across the entire table, and conditionally takes the sums you want depending on whether the `operation_type` be `1` or `2`.  Note that the `CASE` expressions only include the `operation_type` and not the department or date.  The reason this works is because both of your original intended queries share these same `WHERE` conditions, hence we don't need to move them.

Comment: Yes, this should work with Oracle, minus some perhaps minor syntax/naming changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
select operator, target_type, op1, op2, op3, op4
from (query 1) a
full outer join (query 2) b
on (a.operator=b.operator and a.target_type=b.target_type)
order by operator, target_type;
```

Now, both queries are very similar (same date range).  You could do with just 1 query:

```
SELECT operator, target_type, SUM(case when operation_type=1 then sum1 else 0 end) AS op1, SUM(case when operation_type=1 then sum2 else 0 end) AS op2,
SUM(case when operation_type=2 then sum1 else 0 end) AS op3, SUM(case when operation_type=2 then sum2 else 0 end) AS op4
 FROM statistics
WHERE
  department = 1 AND
  operation_type in (1,2) AND
  (date BETWEEN in_start_date AND in_end_date)
GROUP BY operator, target_type
ORDER BY operator, target_type;
```

Comment: Please revise your answer by highlighting each code segment and clicking on the Code Sample button (it's the fifth icon above the box where you enter your answer).